# Initialise Pytorch layer with local random number generator

Tags: numpy, random, pytorch, initialization, deterministic

When writing larger programs that require determinism for random processes, it is generally considered good practice to create function-specific random number generators (rngs) and pass those to the randomness-dependent functions (rather than setting a global seed and have the functions depend on this). See also [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-using-numpy-random-seed-581a9972805f).

For example, when I have a function that generates some sample using numpy, I use a rng that I create at the beginning of the script:

```
# at the beginning of the script
import numpy as np
seed = 5465
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
# much later in the script
def generate_sample(rng, size):
  return rng.random(size)
generate_sample(rng, size=5)
```

I am trying to achieve the same when initialising a `torch.nn.Linear` layer, i.e. use a pre-defined rng to reproducibly initialise the layer.

Is this (reasonably) possible or am I forced to set the Pytorch global seed via `torch.manual_seed()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generators](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Generator.html) are available in Pytorch, and [in-place prngs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#in-place-random-sampling) can rely on this input, e.g. the [normal distribution generator](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.normal_.html#torch.Tensor.normal_).

When it comes to [torch.nn.Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), it has no such parameter, as you observed. You can still manually manage the internal state of the global prng by using a decorator that saves the internal state, loads the desired state, execute your nn.Linear, saves its state, and reset the global prng to its original state. By using this, you rely on roch.manual_seed() but also on the state getter and setter functions to reach states further from the seeded states.

Comment: I've used this solution. It is surprising to me that Pytorch does not allow passing seeds to obviously random processes such as linear layer weights init.